# How Existing Data will be maintained after dropping and recreating the database in EF MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a project with model first approach using Entity Framework in MVC. After some days I needed to add some properties to my existing model. Later when I tried to build the solution it gave me the following error:

> Model has changed.

So, I googled it found one solution:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ClubmansGuideDB>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ClubmansGuideDB>());
```

It's working fine but how does entity framework maintain existing data in particular model associated table? Can someone please explain?

Comment: You will lose all the data, you need to use [migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) approach.

Comment: after  Dropping and Recreating Database i am able to get the existing data even.can you please suggest me with good explanation

Comment: That might happen if you have some seed set up. So the static data will be introduced again, but if you will add 1 new record it should not be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this Initializes, instead, use DB Migration which will generate  a script to only alter the database with the few properties you added to your model.

You can do this:

1- Open NuGet Package Manager Console from Tools Menu->Nu Get Package Manager
2- Run `Enable-Migrations` command
3- Run `Add-Migration Initial` command, this will add a migration with code to create the whole database if this is your first time.
4- If you already have a migration, then run `add-migration -Name somename` 
5- Run the command `update-database -script` this will generate a database script to alter the DB.

Use the script in step #5 and run it against the database and it will only do the needed modifications

Comment: i know the migration process.but i want to know how the data is maintaining after dropping and recreating the database.

Comment: The migration will not drop and create the database, it will generate a script that alters the database, ex: add column, delete column ...
Only the database initializer you are using now drops and creates the database

Comment: but i am able to get the data and update the data using above statement.my question is how Entity Framework maintains data if i drop and recreate the database

Comment: The answer is, it doesn't, if it recreates the database, it means the data will be lost, if this is not happening in your case, then it is not dropping and creating the database, it is just updating it